# Webpack DefinePlugin equivalent for ESBuild

Tags: typescript, webpack, plugins, esbuild

I have a webpack setup that includes the `DefinePlugin`, for injecting computed compile-time values into the bundled code.

Example:

```js
// webpack.config.js
    new DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.APP_BUILD_MODE': JSON.stringify(passedInValueFromCLI)
    })

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// app.ts
// Here, I use the `process.env.APP_BUILD_MODE` that was exposed 
// by the DefinePlugin, in Webpack
const production: boolean = process.env.APP_BUILD_MODE === 'production';
```

I am re-working my build tooling to use ESBuild and need to be able to continue doing something like the above. Is there any equivalent to `DefinePlugin` for ESBuild?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. https://esbuild.github.io/api/#define

It always seems to come down to learning the API doc navigation. ;)